# Does a Jenkins plugin exist that adds stage dependency to a pipeline, similar to how Gradle has dependsOn(), doFirst(), doLast() etc

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I would like to have stages depend on each other to run in a Jenkins pipeline. Ideally I would be able to define the stages in any order within the pipeline, but have them execute according to their dependencies. A simple example being if my 'test' stage depends on the 'build' stage to run but I have 'test' defined first in the pipeline, the pipeline would recognize this and run 'build' before 'test'.

I've looked at a lot of plugins for Jenkins but haven't come across any that deal with stage dependence. I'm relatively new to Jenkins so I may just be looking in the wrong places. So if anybody knows if something like this exists already please let me know. If this doesn't exist already is it something that I could create by making my own Jenkins plugin? Or would this change something fundamental to how Jenkins pipelines work?